# Crystal Reports how can I suppress a group where only one detail record exits

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that groups our invoices by invoice number and details by doc type, original, credit, and rebill.

I want the report to show only those invoices where all three doc types exit.

Obviously 99% of our invoices do not have credit and rebills.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an `invoice group counter` by `doc type` and place a `formula` on your `invoice group` `Section Expert`, `suppress condition` that suppress that section if `invoice group counter` <> 3. This is a solution only if your invoice always have `original, credit, and rebill` one time. If you could have 2 or more originals, credits, and rebills this won't work.

Comment: @LarsSandberg if you think that my answer is correct and helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as answer, so other people can benefit from it. Thanks